# How to create a github pull request using the github API?

Tags: git, github

I have pushed some changes of a repo to a new branch `copyright_updater` on github. The changes are on github.

Now I want to create a pull request. I have been looking at the [API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request) and came up with the following command to create a pull request:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/alex4200/hello-world/pulls" \
  -d '{"head":"copyright_updater","base":"master"}'
```

However, this returns the output

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request"
}
```

So what am I missing this time?

P.S. It does not look if it is an authorization problem. I get the same reply even with a token.

Comment: If you really want to reinvent this wheel may I recommend Postman?

Comment: That is just for testing! In the end I will use python for that. But it has to work first, but it did not.

Comment: Postman will test and then write the curl or python or whatever for you.

Comment: I am using an example from the documentation. That documented example from the documentation should work. Why is it NOT working? What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It does not look if it is an authorization problem.

Maybe not, but since your code shows *no* authorization, I wouldn't expect it to do anything. I was able to get it work just fine, like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/mattneub/temp/pulls' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 55...42' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "base":"main",
    "head":"what",
    "title":"Fun"
}'
```

Apparently the title is required even though the docs do not say so.

Comment: It turned out I was using a wrong github token. The token I was using was a github token, but for a different project. So the actual bug here is the message "Not found", which is incorrect. I will create a bug report with github

Comment: In general my experience is that when a programmer says Whatever the issue maybe, it certainly isn't X, it's probably X. Still, my answer is right; the push did not succeed until I added the Title, so that's a bug in the API docs.

Comment: Ah so maybe it was the title missing. That could be. Thanks for the info. 
However, I have a different error doing the exact same github api request with python.

Comment: @Alex I totally agree with you, this message is wrong! How did you solve it? I'm using a GitHub Personal Access Token with full permission and still getting Not Found.

Comment: @JoabeLucena I am not sure I solved the problem with curl, as I am using the API access successfully with python now. It seemed, I used a wrong token. I would triple check you are using the correct token with the correct access rights

Comment: @Alex I would try with python now. I created the token on: GitHub > Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Tokens with FULL permission. Is this the way you did? And, could you post the code here pls? I ask u because I'm passing the token like this: `curl -H 'Authorization: token <token_goes_here>' https://github.com/MyComp/MyRepo/pull/99`

and it's not working =/

Comment: @Alex here's my Python example (where `r` is `requests`): `r.get('https://github.com/MyOrg/MyRepo/pull/99', headers= {'Authorization': '<token>'})` still Not Found =(

Comment: @JoabeLucena I have in my header also the entry `"Accept": "application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json"`

Comment: @Al What about the token, did generate just like mine?

Answer (score -1):

You put the URL in `""` but that is not in the documentation. Try:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/alex4200/hello-world/pulls \
  -d '{"head":"copyright_updater","base":"master"}'
```

Comment: It does not matter. I get the same result